# Nextjs Set Width to Actual Size

Tags: javascript, css, next.js

I made an Website with Nextjs, but I have an problem with mobile responsiveness

[Source code](https://github.com/kaaax0815/geis-bus-schedule)

The body is not the same size as the actual size. I have an unresponsive table which makes a overflow, but the container itself, is not the size as the table

[image: Body wrong size]

The marked part is the body, but as you can see the actual size is way bigger

Can you help me? I am new the css and dont really like it, but mobile ui/ux is important

Comment: Please use Codesandbox to fork your code and show a demo.

Comment: i sugget to use something similar to antd tables : see this https://imgur.com/2hH8Ris

Comment: @m4n0 a demo is avaible here: https://brave-feynman-a25437.netlify.app/8304. If you need i can also create a codesandbox

Comment: @Nico does this work with column based tables? And could you provide the source code to that what you did?

Comment: @kaaaxcreators i created a codesandob from your repo 
 see : https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-waterfall-hxv8z?file=/pages/%5Blinie%5D.js and https://hxv8z.sse.codesandbox.io/8304

Comment: @Nico <3 much thanks. i dont know if i should make a overflow for the table or your implemenation. Can I change the count of the pages? on the bottom where you switch through the table?

Comment: @kaaaxcreators you can customize pretty much everything see docs : https://ant.design/components/table/

Comment: @Nico Can you please make an answer, so it gets marked as answered and other people see it?

Comment: @kaaaxcreators since the problem is not next.js related and is more an advice than a real solution i think is better to keep it as a comment :)